# Persistent data storage in Cordova using Monaca.io

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, local-storage, monaca

I am having a problem where app settings in localStorage is sometimes being deleted for some of my users in iOS. I understand that iOS will delete these if space is needed. My app is built using Monaca.io/Cordova/OnsenUI/JQuery. Can someone suggest a solution that will persist these data reliably? I have heard that WebSQL is on it's way out and for my purposes this is likely overkill. I am just storing a set of liked entities in JSON.

Comment: Might also be overkill, but you can use the Cordova SQLite plugins available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monaca runs cordova (aka phonegap) under the hood, so it accepts it's plugins. One that solves your problem is [NativeStorate](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage), just check it out.